# setText() error, Method cannot resolve for TextView

Tags: java, android

Method cannot resolve for TextView in this code
What is wrong with this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    EditText Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmployerNameEdit);

    String userName = Username.getText().toString();
    TextView changedName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerName);
    changedName.setText(userName);

}
```

Comment: Hello, you need to rewrite your question in order to add more details. Please check this link :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Put all what you write inside `onCreate`.

Comment: add xml code for this particular `textView` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing in oncreate or create global edittext and TextView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 EditText Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmployerNameEdit);

String userName = Username.getText().toString();
TextView changedName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerName);
changedName.setText(userName);


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

might be you missed curly bracket,

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmployerNameEdit);

    String userName = Username.getText().toString();
    TextView changedName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerName);
    changedName.setText(userName);
}
```

}

if you still getting problem, please fell free to ask question. :)